# Merge [decimalformat] into [decimal-format]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[decimalformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decimalformat) and [decimal-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decimal-format) are completely identical, both referring to the Java `DecimalFormat` class. They should obviously be merged.